# Loading the model with nsfwjs

Tags: javascript

*(Nsfwjs is a anti-nsfw package)* I'm trying to use nsfwjs package, but when I need to load the model (`nsfwjs.load(...)`), it gives me the error `Only absolute URLs are supported`. I downloaded the model from a website but it doesn't work,
I tried `./model`, `/model/` and others... What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct your url something like this:

```
const model = await nsfw.load('file://model/', {size: 299})
```

or this:

```
const model = await nsfw.load('file://./model/', {size: 299})
```